# Reset primary key auto_increment

Tags: mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reset primary key in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809893/reset-primary-key-in-mysql)

Is there any solution to when I

```
delete from t1;
```

and then insert entities force the id to begin from id=1 again?

```
insert into t1 values(...);
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> ***[...] then insert entities force the id to begin from id=1 again?***

You can `ALTER TABLE` like this:

```
ALTER TABLE t1 AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
```

Documentation here: [MySQL ALTER TABLE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/alter-table.html)

Answer (score 3):

Try truncate table
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/truncate-table.html

This resets auto_increment columns back to 0.