# Rails seed: How to truncate DB table?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Before seeding test data into DB table I need to truncate the table (I need to reset primary key), I am trying to do that this way:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("TRUNCATE users")
```

but when I print out data from DB, I still don't see counting primary key from 1.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

Also, I've tried manually run in terminal to PostgreSQL database

```
truncate users
```

But the primary count still doesn't start from 1.

**SOLUTION:**

In Postgres, run:

```
ALTER SEQUENCE users_id_seq RESTART WITH 1;
```

Comment: This isn't really a rails issue. You'll need to execute the correct SQL for your database to change the auto_increment value. You could drop the table and recreate it, but that may be overkill. See this question on stack overflow for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6241684/reset-primary-key-auto-increment

Comment: Thanks Scott, if you don't mind, I will post a solution that helped me.

Answer (score 7):

In **MySQL**, `TRUNCATE table;` deletes all rows *and* resets the auto increment counter.

In **PostgreSQL** it does not do this automatically. You can use `TRUNCATE TABLE table RESTART IDENTITY;`.

Just for the record: In **SQLite**, there is no `TRUNCATE` statement, instead, it's

```
DELETE FROM table;
DELETE FROM sqlite_sequence WHERE name='table';
```

Answer (score 7):

In case your db is postgres, you can do something like this to truncate the db tables of your models:

```
[
  MyModel1,
  MyModel2,
  MyModel3
].each do |m|
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("TRUNCATE TABLE #{m.table_name} RESTART IDENTITY;")
end
```

Answer (score 5):

*This is too late I'm answering this question but I hope this will help someone else.*
You've to install *(OR you can add `gem 'database_cleaner'` to your Gemfile)* a GEM called [Database Cleaner](https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner) which helps to clean your database without affecting your database schema._
To clean your database each time whenever you do `rake db:seed` then paste

```
DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
```

on the top of your seed file. ***It'll clear your database and start count from `1` again.***
***Disclaimer :** This updated answer is tested, and working perfectly in my system*.

Answer (score 0):

From within Rails in a csv_upload.rb I used and it worked.

`ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute('TRUNCATE model_name RESTART IDENTITY')`